# Envelope distort not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: I want to join those with Envelope Distort]

I'm trying to wrap the lines within the shape in Illustrator. The lines are in a layer under the shape. When I use Envelope Distort to do put the wrap the lines with the shape it returns this:
[image: Not what I want]

This is not what I'm trying to achieve.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use the envelop command. Use the blend by selecting the top and bottom curves  of your envelop and go to `Object>Blend>Make`.. make sue that the top and the bottom path only must be extracted from the sides paths.

Comment: @hsawires make that into an answer and I'll upvote it! :)

Comment: Hi kallilalli, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I have Just added my answer @Vincent .. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see that putting a blended object into an envelop will work fine. in my opinion it should be blended from the envelop itself.

please follow my steps for best results:

1. draw the path as it show and give the upper path an orange stroke while tje bottom one blue stroke.

[image]

2. now select the both paths and go to `Objects>Blend>Make` or just click <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>  you should see something like the shape hereunder. this shape is smooth color blended, the next setp is to adjust the steps of the blended paths.

[image]

3. Select the generated shape and go to `Objects>Blend>Blend Options...` and select from the drop down menu `Specified steps` and in the input text field type the steps that you want, let's make it 30 steps. make sure to check the preview checkbox for live preview.

[image]

4. press ok and you should have a nicer blended shape using the Blend tool instead of using the Envelop tool.
   [image]

Comment: Great tip, however the question was - why Envelope does not work, not "what are other options". Anyway, great answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Place a shaping object over the lines and Use Top object option to distort in a mentioned way:

[image]

Comment: That works. I believe that the problem was that shape had a white fill.